# PHP rename files contain special characters "/" and " "

Tags: php, file-rename

How to rename file  with name containing "/", in  PHP 
example  : "A / B"

```
$filename= "A / B";
rename("1.html", $filename.".html");
```

doesn't work!

Comment: You can't do this on the vast majority of operating systems since `/` is used as a path delimeter for directories. Also "doesn't work !!!" is not a description of a problem. Check out [ask].

Comment: i can use  `$filename = str_replace ("/", "-", $filename);` but i dont wanna change the original name of file

Comment: I really doubt the original name of the file contained a `/` character. And you should most likely be doing quite a bit of sanitization on these filenames if you are receiving them from a user via the web.

Comment: @filip The original name is `1.html`, it doesn't have `/` in it.

Comment: are you serious !!!

Comment: @filip Please do not forget to mark the coorect answert with the checkmark. ;)

Answer (score 1):

On linux machines and on OSX, the forward slash (/) is a forbidden character. The file system will not let you use this character in a filename.

Comment: Windows since at least 2000 as well.

Comment: @filip Essentially, yes, there is no way. There might exist some file system that doesn't forbid it (I think the Rackspace CloudFiles storage system might not) but for any normal file system I think you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I try it and it is possible to modify the string, but as the other users say... it is possible/you will run into a problem with your OS. Becouse the `/` caracter is used by tree  of the OS.

```
/                 --> is root
/folderX          --> is the folde X in the root folder
/folderX/yourFile --> is the file in the folderX in the root folder
```

This is the code I run on the [website](http://phpfiddle.org/)

```
<?php
$filename = "this/is/a/test";

$filename = str_replace("/", "-", $filename);
var_dump($filename)

?>
```

And this is the result

```
string(14) "this-is-a-test"
```

As you see this is a path to a file called test `this/is/a/test`

And this a filename without a path `this-is-a-test`

I hope this answer helps you to see the difference.